# Opening pdf in new tab using a png image with jspdf works in Mozilla, but not Chrome or Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot, jspdf

I create a flot graph on my html website and want to be able to export it to a pdf (on the click of a button) which should open in a new tab, for people to decide if they want to download it to their computers or not.

I started with jpeg and it was working fine, but the background appears black because of transparency issues, so I changed to png.

After this my code crashes the Chrome browser, or opens a new empty tab! Same for Internet Explorer... In Mozilla it seems to work fine. Saving the pdf to file rather than opening in new window works perfect in all browsers, but I'd rather not fill people's download folders with junk they may not want.

I created a fiddle to reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/8tLt9yof/10/

jQuery code inside the "Get pdf" button reads (plot is the name of my flot graph):

```
var canvas = plot.getCanvas();
var src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
doc.addImage(src, 'PNG', 10, 20, 280, 150);
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

Can anybody help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like an issue with Chrome, not your code. [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/481) talks about it and a few potential fixes, but I wasn't able to get them to work in Chrome. You could do some sort of browser detection and save if Chrome, otherwise open in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you, @prmech. I read that browser detection is highly discouraged, and that feature detection should be used instead. Do you happen to know how to implement that in this case?